# $1/z$ continuous on complex plane minus origin

Tags: analysis

Is $1/z$ continuous on $\mathbb C \setminus 0$? I can prove it's continuous on $\mathbb C \setminus B(0,c)$:

$$ \left | {1/z - 1/y } \right |  = \left | {y-z \over yz } \right |$$
and if $z,y \ge c >0$ then this can be bounded. But what to do on  $\mathbb C \setminus 0$?

Comment: If $f,g$ continuous and $g\neq 0$ then $f/g....$

Comment: I guess you can prove it for an _arbitrary_ $c > 0$? Note that continuity is a local property, and for $z \neq 0$, choose $c \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\lvert z\rvert$ to see that it is continuous in $z$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes for an arbitrary $c>0$. Thank you for the comment, I understand that Clark's comment and yours show two different arguments. It is interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is right. It proves that $z\mapsto 1/z$ is (uniformly) continuous on $\mathbb C \setminus B(0,c)$ for all $c>0$. This suffices to prove that it is continuous on $\mathbb C \setminus 0$. It is just not uniformly continuous there.

Comment: Could you add a proof showing that if $f: \mathbb C \setminus 0 \to \mathbb C$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb C \setminus B(0,c)$ for every $c>0$ then $f$ is continuous at $0$? It is not clear to me how it works. I do understand the argument with $f/g$ pointed out to me in the comments but I'm interested in this other argument too.